# Writing text in a node that is sloped

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code is rendered to depict three parallel lines `k`, `\ell`, and `m`, and two traversals `s` and `t`.  The intersections of `k`, `\ell`, and `m` and `s` are called `A`, `B`, and `C`, respectively.  (The labels for these points are not displayed.)  I have labeled the length of the line segment `AB` as `x + 5` and the length of the line segment `BC` at `4x + 5`.

There are two modifications that I would like to have.  First, I would like the labels `x + 5` and `4x + 5` to be half as far from the line below them as the line above them.  (The horizontal lines are "stacked" with `k` on top and `m` on bottom. So, the points `A`, `B`, and `C` are stacked with `A` on top and `C` on bottom.)  Second, I would like the nodes for `x + 5` and `4x + 5` typeset in the same direction as the lines `k`, `\ell`, and `m`. Here is the command that I used to typeset `4x + 5`, for example. I also have a green line drawn to illustrate where I want the node.  It illustrates the slight error in placement of the node.

```
\node[anchor=15, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!{2/3}!(C)$) +(195:0.3)$){$4x+5$};

\draw[line width=0.2pt, green] ($(B)!{2/3}!(C)$) -- ($($(B)!{2/3}!(C)$) +({195}:2)$);
```

All four `node` commands are at the end of the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Three parallel lines k, \ell, and m are drawn. Two traversals s and t are to be drawn.
%The ratios of the lengths of the line segments along the traversals between k and \ell
%to the lengths of the line segments along the traversals between \ell and m is to be
%3 to 2.
%
%A, B, and C are points on t; C is a point on line m, B is a point on line ell, and A is
%a point on line k.  P, Q, and R are points on s; R is a point on line m, Q is a point
%on line ell, and P is a point on line k. The length of line segment AB is 6, and the
%length of line segment BC is 9. To maintain the same ratio between corresponding points
%on line s, a circle of radius 6 about R is drawn and one of the intersections with line
%ell is labeled Q, and a circle of radius 4 about Q is drawn and one of the intersections
%with line k is labeled P.
\path[name path=line_m] (0,0) -- (15:15);
\coordinate (C) at (15:5);
\coordinate (R) at (15:12);
\coordinate (B) at ($(C) +(50:2.25)$);
\path[name path=line_ell, latex-latex] ($(B) +(195:3)$) -- ($(B) +(15:12)$);
\path[name path=circular_arc_to_locate_Q] (R) circle (1.5);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_ell and circular_arc_to_locate_Q}];
\coordinate (Q) at (intersection-2);
\coordinate (A) at ($(B) +(50:1.5)$);
\path[name path=line_k, latex-latex] ($(A) +(195:3)$) -- ($(A) +(15:9)$);
\path[name path=circular_arc_to_locate_P] (Q) circle (1);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_k and circular_arc_to_locate_P}];
\coordinate (P) at (intersection-2);

\draw[latex-latex] ($(C) +(195:3)$) -- ($(R) +(15:2)$);
\node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$m$};
\draw[latex-latex] ($(B) +(195:3)$) -- ($(Q) +(15:2)$);
\node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$\ell$};
\draw[latex-latex] ($(A) +(195:3)$) -- ($(P) +(15:2)$);
\node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$k$};


%Traversals s and t are drawn. Invisible lines parallel to k, \ell, and m
%that pass through the arrowheads of s are used to bound t.
\draw[name path=path_for_traversal_t, latex-latex] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(R) +(\n1:1)$) -- ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1)$);
\draw let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-180}, inner sep=0] at ($($(R) +(\n1:1)$) +(\n1:0.15)$){$t$};

\path[name path=path_for_traversal_s] ($(C) +(-130:2)$) -- ($(A) + (50:2)$);
\path[name path=path_for_the_lower_arrowhead_of_s] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(R) +(\n1:1)$) -- ($(R) +(\n1:1) +(195:11)$);
\path[name path=path_for_the_upper_arrowhead_of_s] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1)$) -- ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1) +(195:7)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_traversal_s and path_for_the_lower_arrowhead_of_s, by={lower_arrowhead_for_s}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_traversal_s and path_for_the_upper_arrowhead_of_s, by={upper_arrowhead_for_s}}];
\draw[latex-latex] (lower_arrowhead_for_s) -- (upper_arrowhead_for_s);
\draw let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=50, inner sep=0] at ($(lower_arrowhead_for_s) +(-130:0.15)$){$s$};


%The lengths of the line segments on the traversals between the parallel lines are typeset.
\node[anchor=15, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.5!(B)$) +(195:0.3)$){$x+5$};
\draw[line width=0.2pt, green] ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) -- ($($(A)!0.5!(B)$) +({195}:2)$);
\node[anchor=15, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$) +(195:0.3)$){$4x+5$};
\draw[line width=0.2pt, green] ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) -- ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$) +({195}:2)$);
\draw node[anchor=195, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(P)!0.5!(Q)$) +(15:0.3)$){$4$};
\draw[line width=0.2pt, green] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(P)!0.5!(Q)$) -- ($($(P)!0.5!(Q)$) +(15:2)$);
\draw node[anchor=195, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(Q)!0.5!(R)$) +(15:0.3)$){$6$};
\draw[line width=0.2pt, green] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(Q)!0.5!(R)$) -- ($($(Q)!0.5!(R)$) +(15:2)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\node[sloped,...] {...}`.

Comment: @Zarko  I did try that.  To use `sloped`, you have be be using a `path` command, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[EDITED to use 1/3 rather than 1/2 as I initially misread the desiderata in the question.]

[image: sloped labels]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %Three parallel lines k, \ell, and m are drawn. Two traversals s and t are to be drawn.
    %The ratios of the lengths of the line segments along the traversals between k and \ell
    %to the lengths of the line segments along the traversals between \ell and m is to be
    %3 to 2.
    %
    %A, B, and C are points on t; C is a point on line m, B is a point on line ell, and A is
    %a point on line k.  P, Q, and R are points on s; R is a point on line m, Q is a point
    %on line ell, and P is a point on line k. The length of line segment AB is 6, and the
    %length of line segment BC is 9. To maintain the same ratio between corresponding points
    %on line s, a circle of radius 6 about R is drawn and one of the intersections with line
    %ell is labeled Q, and a circle of radius 4 about Q is drawn and one of the intersections
    %with line k is labeled P.
    \path[name path=line_m] (0,0) -- (15:15);
    \coordinate (C) at (15:5);
    \coordinate (R) at (15:12);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(C) +(50:2.25)$);
    \path[name path=line_ell, latex-latex] ($(B) +(195:3)$) -- ($(B) +(15:12)$);
    \path[name path=circular_arc_to_locate_Q] (R) circle (1.5);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=line_ell and circular_arc_to_locate_Q}];
    \coordinate (Q) at (intersection-2);
    \coordinate (A) at ($(B) +(50:1.5)$);
    \path[name path=line_k, latex-latex] ($(A) +(195:3)$) -- ($(A) +(15:9)$);
    \path[name path=circular_arc_to_locate_P] (Q) circle (1);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=line_k and circular_arc_to_locate_P}];
    \coordinate (P) at (intersection-2);

    \draw[latex-latex] ($(C) +(195:3)$) coordinate (c) -- ($(R) +(15:2)$) coordinate (r);
    \node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$m$};
    \draw[latex-latex] ($(B) +(195:3)$) coordinate (b) -- ($(Q) +(15:2)$) coordinate (q);
    \node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$\ell$};
    \draw[latex-latex] ($(A) +(195:3)$) coordinate (a) -- ($(P) +(15:2)$) coordinate (p);
    \node[anchor=195, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(15:2) +(15:0.15)$){$k$};

    %Traversals s and t are drawn. Invisible lines parallel to k, \ell, and m
    %that pass through the arrowheads of s are used to bound t.
    \draw[name path=path_for_traversal_t, latex-latex] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(R) +(\n1:1)$) -- ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1)$);
    \draw let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-180}, inner sep=0] at ($($(R) +(\n1:1)$) +(\n1:0.15)$){$t$};

    \path[name path=path_for_traversal_s] ($(C) +(-130:2)$) -- ($(A) + (50:2)$);
    \path[name path=path_for_the_lower_arrowhead_of_s] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(R) +(\n1:1)$) -- ($(R) +(\n1:1) +(195:11)$);
    \path[name path=path_for_the_upper_arrowhead_of_s] let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1)$) -- ($(P) +({\n1-180}:1) +(195:7)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_traversal_s and path_for_the_lower_arrowhead_of_s, by={lower_arrowhead_for_s}}];
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_traversal_s and path_for_the_upper_arrowhead_of_s, by={upper_arrowhead_for_s}}];
    \draw[latex-latex] (lower_arrowhead_for_s) -- (upper_arrowhead_for_s);
    \draw let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=50, inner sep=0] at ($(lower_arrowhead_for_s) +(-130:0.15)$){$s$};

%   \foreach \i in {A,B,C,P,Q,R,a,b,c,r,q,p} \node at (\i) {\i};

    %The lengths of the line segments on the traversals between the parallel lines are typeset.
    \draw node[inner sep=0] at ($($(P)!0.3!90:(Q)$)!{2/3}!($(Q)!0.3!-90:(P)$)$) {$4$};
    \draw node[inner sep=0] at ($($(Q)!0.3!90:(R)$)!{2/3}!($(R)!0.3!-90:(Q)$)$) {$6$};
    \path ($(a)!2/3!(b)$) -- ($(p)!2/3!(q)$) node [pos=.25, sloped] {$x+5$};
    \path ($(b)!2/3!(c)$) -- ($(q)!2/3!(r)$) node [pos=.2, sloped] {$4x+5$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you really want the labels centred on the green line, you should use `1/2` rather than `2/3`:

```
    \path ($(a)!.5!(b)$) -- ($(p)!.5!(q)$) node [pos=.25, sloped] {$x+5$};
    \path ($(b)!.5!(c)$) -- ($(q)!.5!(r)$) node [pos=.2, sloped] {$4x+5$};

    \draw[line width=0.2pt, green] ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) -- ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$) +({195}:2)$);
```

[image: zoom on green line]

Alternatively, you could rotate the nodes, but this seemed easier. If you want to use this, you can just use `rotate=<angle>` in the options to the node. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,30,60,...,330}
    \node [rotate=\i, draw] at (2*\j,0) {angle \i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated nodes]

Comment: Yes, that is the diagram that I want.  Actually, the directions were to have `x + 5` half the distance from line `\ell` as it is from line `k` and to have `4x + 5` half the distance from line `m` as it is from line `\ell`.  I guess that I replace `0.5!` in your code with `{1/3}!`.  Why didn't my code give me that?

Comment: I see that `\coordinate (a)`, `\coordinate (b)`, and `\coordinate (c)` are the left arrowheads of lines `k`, `\ell`, and `m`, respectively, and that `\coordinate (p)`, `\coordinate (q)`, and `\coordinate (r)` are the right arrowheads of lines `k`, `\ell`, and `m`, respectively. So, in your path command `\path ($(a)!.5!(b)$) -- ($(p)!.5!(q)$) node [pos=.25, sloped] {$x+5$};`, the start is halfway between the left arrowheads of `k` and `\ell`, and the end is halfway between the right arrowheads of `k` and `\ell`. I understand the issuance of this command.

Comment: Please give me the code for rotating a node.  That may be more convenient for me.

Comment: Oh, I misread it. Yes, you can say `1/3` for `0.5`. I did it quickly while taking a break.

Comment: I edited the code in my post.  This gives me almost what I want.  The placement of the node `4` is exactly what I want.  It seems to me that the placement of the `6` is a bit - less than `1pt` - too high, and the placement of `x+5` and `4x+5` are too low.  This is made evident by the green line segments that my code draws.  Please edit my code so that the nodes `6`, `x+5`, and `4x+5` are centered on the green lines.

Comment: EDIT 1: I've edited my answer so that it uses a ratio of 2:1 as you originally requested and also added the requested code for node rotation, demonstrated with a simple example. Hope this helps. EDIT 2: I've added a further edit explaining that if you want the labels centred on the green line, then you should use a ratio of 1:1 rather than 2:1. This is illustrated by the zoomed in image towards the end of my post.

Comment: Why doesn't the code `\node[anchor=15, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$) +(195:0.3)$){$4x+5$};` typeset `4x+5` centered along the green line?  There is some misunderstanding that I have regarding the `node` command.

Comment: It seems that if I replace `anchor=15` with `anchor=0` or with `anchor=east` in the options for the nodes for `x+5` and `4x+5`, I get the same positioning as you have.  Why is `anchor=15` the wrong specification?

Comment: Well, it depends where you want it to end up. Try `\node at (0,0) {0,0};` for control purposes and then play around e.g. add `\node [draw,blue, anchor=15] at (0,0) {15};` The anchor is placed at the position the node is located at, in this case the origin. So `anchor=east` places the node so that the centre-eastern point on the border is at the origin, whereas `anchor=north east` would place the north-eastern border point at the origin. You can always say `\path [fill=red] (<node>.15) circle (.5pt);` to see where the relevant anchor is and what's happening.

Comment: But  it is hard to say why something isn't. The question, really, is why you think it should be the right specification.

Comment: The command `\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, rotate=15, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$) +(195:0.3)$){$4x+5$};` gives me the positioning of the label `4x+5' that I want.  The green line divides the node horizontally into two equal parts.

Comment: Apparently, when a node has the specification `rotate=15`, the specification `anchor=east` is rendered as `anchor=15` with respect to the `tikzpicture` environment.  Likewise,  when a node has the specification `rotate=15`, the specification `anchor=east` is rendered as `anchor=90+15` with respect to the `tikzpicture` environment.  This is what I needed to know about the `node` command.

Comment: By the way, now you know that your comment "if you really want the labels centred on the green line, you should use `1/2` rather than `2/3` is not right.  The command `\node[anchor=east, rotate=15,  inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!{2/3}!(C)$) +(195:0.3)$){$4x+5$};` centers `4x+5` horizontally across the green line.